# How to get pictures or product photos/images for an ecommerce website

Tags: image, e-commerce, photos

I am developing an ecommerce website (Fashion related). I wanted to know how to get the images for the product to upload in website. I see in most of the websites high definition photos are used with models. Do I need to actually look for a photo shoot of my products or if there are some tools which I can download and use?

I am confused on this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  If you need images of items you will be selling, then you'll need to somehow get these images.  Simply downloading them off the internet isn't going to cut it.  If you're developing it for a client, then it's the client's responsibility to provide you with the images.

Comment: ok. You mean to say photos with models donning those apparels will be supplied by clients. What if I am getting those apparels from a local manufacturer and selling it. I mean when I am the one acting as shopkeeper maintaining a site.

Comment: If you are the seller, then it's up to you to arrange for the pictures.  Manufacturers may be able to supply you with some of them, but no guarantee.  Often shops would arrange a photo shoot to get pictures of models.  Depending on where in the world you are, it may not be as expensive as you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned about the Fashion related website, so i believe you need to put some money and efforts in order to tell user about your products.

As a customer why would i purchase at your site if the original pictures of the product is not there.
Working in E commerce domain from so long gave me a good overview of the client mind set and when it related to Fashion, everyone including me would like to see a good images of the product i am going to buy.

My suggestion for you is to put some efforts and get good quality images else i am afraid that people will not find good interest in your product no matter how good / best are the products.